# Spark Filter producing different results than groupby - count

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pySpark.
The following code bewilders me. Can anyone explain why the different results?

As far as I understand, the results below should be identical.
Thanks!

```
train_df.groupBy("action").count().collect()
```

produces:

```
[Row(action=u'purchase', count=9017), Row(action=u'browse', count=52205)]
```

Those counts (above) are correct and have been verified.

But if I do this:

```
print train_df.filter("action = 'purchase'").count()
print train_df.filter("action = 'browse'").count()
```

I get:

```
5739
20336
```

Why are those counts different??

Comment: can you recreate this with a portion of the data (maybe something you can share?)

Comment: I'm working off this code: https://github.com/actionml/analysis-tools/blob/master/split_and_analyze.ipynb

The split looks like this (for my code):
`train_df = df.filter(F.col("Date") < split_date).select("userID", "action", "productID").cache()
test_df =  df.filter(F.col("Date") >= split_date).select("userID", "action", "productID").cache()`

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense to me. No matter what happens upstream this is unpredictable behavior, at best. Can anyone explain any way this discrepancy could happen?